# Delay a link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

Here's the fiddle I'm working with: http://jsfiddle.net/Scd9b/

How can I delay the href function after the click?

For example a user clicks on the link, the message slides down *One moment...* and after 2 seconds the user continues to the page its linked to.

Sorry everybody forgot to mention there are some anchors that are not linked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simulate navigating to a page by settings window.location. So we will block the normal function of the link with `preventDefault` and then in a `setTimeout`, we will set the correct window.location:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PePLbv

```
$("a.question[href]").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.href) {
        var target = this.href;
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location = target;
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: But I also have some anchors that are not linked. Those are being redirected to an undefined URL. Any way to get this script working with out redirecting the unlinked anchors?

Comment: What do you mean by unlinked?

Comment: `<a class="question">Hello</a>`

Comment: Please include your code in the answer as well as on jsfiddle (link now dead).

Answer (score 6):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C87wM/1/

Modify your toggle like this:

```
$("a.question[href]").click(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(2000, function() {
        window.location.href = self.attr('href'); // go to href after the slide animation completes
    });
    return false; // And also make sure you return false from your click handler.
});
```

Comment: +1 for using the completion function of the animation rather than a `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @Purmou This way we can be sure that the user sees the full animation. Also this way, we need not worry about making sure that the link delay is more than the animation duration. i.e. we can freely use slow or fast or 2000 etc.

Comment: Well this makes the animation take 2 seconds and have the page redirect right after. Shouldn't it show the message for 2 whole seconds then redirect?

Comment: $(this).attr('href') is undefined in the slideToggle callback. $(this) refers to $("#active") in the scope of the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Cancel the click and use setTimeout to change the location.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("span.answer").hide();

    $("a.question").click(function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
        e.preventDefault();
        var loc = this.href;
        if(loc){
            window.setTimeout( function(){ window.location.href=loc; }, 2000 );
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: But I also have some anchors that are not linked. Those are being redirected to an undefined URL. Any way to get this script working with out redirecting the unlinked anchors?

Comment: check to see if loc has a value. edited code. or you can use a selector that makes sure it has an href. a.question[href]

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("span.answer").hide();

    $("a.question").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
        var Link = $(this).attr("href");
        setTimeout(function()
        {
             window.location.href = Link;
        },2000);
    });

});
```

Comment: But I also have some anchors that are not linked. Those are being redirected to an undefined URL. Any way to get this script working with out redirecting the unlinked anchors?

Comment: @user1090389 - For that use the `$("a.question[href]")` selector instead of `$("a.question")`

Comment: @techfoobar But I still want the animation to work on those that are not linked...

Comment: `this` will be `window` inside the setTimeout callback so this won't work as written.  You would have to either save the URL or `this` to a different variable before the setTimeout call.

Answer (score 1):

2024 edit, Vanilla JS:

```js
for (const link of document.links) {
    link.addEventListener("click", e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(() => location.href = link.href, 2000);
    });
}
```

Original 2012 answer:

---

This should do it:

```js
$("a[href]").click(function () {
    var url = this.href;
    setTimeout(function () {
        location.href = url;
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the default action of the link, first of all. Then add a timeout of 2 seconds, after which the page is redirected to the `url` found in the `href` attribute of the link.

```
$("a.question").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    setTimeout(function(){
        location.href = $(this).prop("href");
    }, 2000);
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/Scd9b/2/).

Comment: Only `prop()`. Replace it with `attr()` and you'll be fine. Though I recommend using the latest version anyways.

Comment: I wish... my site won't let me.

Comment: `this` will be `window` inside the setTimeout callback so this won't work as written.  You would have to either save the URL or `this` to a different variable before the setTimeout call.

Answer (score 0):

How about e.preventDefault in your click handler. Then do a setTimeout that takes you to your destination?

```
$("a.question").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    setTimeout('window.location.href=' + $(this).attr(href), 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting window location didn't sound like a good idea to me, So here's what I did

On click it checks whether the user clicked the link if yes it waits 2 seconds then triggers the click again and since it's not user-triggered it doesn't wait this time

```js
document.getElementById("question").addEventListener("click", function(e) {

 //if user clicked prevent default and trigger after 2 seconds
 if(e.isTrusted) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  //after 2 seconds click it and it'll not wait since it's not user triggered 
  setTimeout(function() {
     e.target.click();
  }, 2000);
 }
});
```

```html
<a href="https://www.bing.com" id="question">Bing</a>
```