# How to hold a page for 5 second before redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a page with a link to another page.
I want to hold page for 5 second before it redirects to another page.

I am using jquery and javascript with HTML5 and CSS3.

Comment: Don't. Seriously. Plenty of people don't give their full attention to webpages. They do other things while pages load. If something is importent enough to show to the visitor, then it is important enough to continue to show until they click a link to continue. If it isn't important enough, then use an HTTP redirect so you don't mess up the browser history (and thus the back button).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delay a link click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775541/delay-a-link-click)

Comment: @Quentin: Then again, see download links on Sourceforge et al. Anyway, I think the OP means after a link has been manually clicked.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit — Those download links are awful. They break copy/pasting a link into a nicer download tool and the pages are among the messiest, least usable I've encountered.

Comment: Not sure why the question has been downvoted, its a reasonable question regardless of the motives?

Comment: Quentin - Thanks for your suggestion, I know the drawbacks and other stuff u explained. I've just seen such thing somewhere and I was curious to find out how. Thats it.

Comment: @ChrisDowdeswell exactly, you downvote when a question does not have enough detail, not when it's generally against accepted practices.

Comment: @Quentin: Yet, that aside, considering only the redirect mechanism, the delay is perfectly valid since it doesn't make you leave the page.

Comment: @ChrisDowdeswell: I downvoted, because this is not a programming question but a "make me this feature". It shows zero research effort.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: There are more reasons than that for downvoting. Have a look on meta where they are listed.

Comment: It might be worth giving people the heads up especially when they are new the to site. I had a similar experience when I posted to english.se and people offered only hostility towards me for posting a question which wasn't in the right format, it was really off-putting for me. Lets not lose the community aspect of the site, suggest a close or edit the question rather than taking the easy option of a downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use event-handlers with `setTimeout()` for this like that:

```
jQuery('a.external').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location = href;
    }, 5000);
});
```

This should work for every anchor you assign a class of "`external`".

Answer (score 1):

In javascript:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.assign('http://www.google.com');
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [the setTimeout method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout):

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.assign('http://yourWebsite.com/otherPage');
}), 5000);
```