# click sound on <a> tag before it moves to another page

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I want to give click sound to all  tags on the page before they moves to another page.

I could easily play click sound using  tag.. but it doesn't work well because the page already moves to the linked page before I hear the sound.

My code to play sound is as follows:

```
<audio id="audio" hidden>
<source src="./sound/sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

$('#menu li a').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); // If I use this, it doesn't goes to another page. But I can here the sound. I want to play the sound and the link both.
var sound = $("#audio");
sound.get(0).play();
});
```

Any tip would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775541/delay-a-link-click it is similar to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Just a side note, most people would find this really annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need... this will play the audio and once the audio finishes playing, goes to the target location...

**HTML**

```
<audio id="audio" hidden>
    <source src="./sound/sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<div id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Click to play...</a>
    </li>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var target;

function checkAudio() {
    if($("#audio")[0].paused) {
        window.location.href  = target;
    } else {
        setTimeout(checkAudio, 1000);
    }
}

$('#menu li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    target = $(this).attr('href');

    console.log("Let's play");

    var sound = $("#audio");
    sound.get(0).play();

    setTimeout(checkAudio, 1000);
});
```

The code checks for the state of the audio each second, you can change the value of timeout to check less frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
  $('#menu li a').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var sound = $("#audio");
       sound.get(0).play();

       setTimeout(function () {
           window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
       }, 3000);

   });
```

Comment: That will prevent navigation

Comment: I totally forgot about that one! let me fix it

Comment: does this wait for the play to finish to change location? in that case it would be better than just waiting a fixed time as my answer

Comment: it doesn't I've just updated my answer, since Ktash stated that my previous will prevent page navigation. and the Poster wanted to play a sound before navigating away from the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a delay and still go to the page you want you can do it like this.

```
$('#menu li a').click(function(e) {
          var destination = $(this).attr('href');
             e.preventDefault();
             var sound = $("#audio");
           sound.get(0).play();
 setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = destination; }, 1000);
    });
```

Just set the time of the sound or how much time you want to wait.

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the page before control goes to the other page. for that use return false(to stop the page) and return true(to shift the control). The code below may be ugly but I think it will work for you

```
<script>
   function playsound()
   {
     return false;
     var sound = $("#audio");
     if(sound.get(0).play())
       return true;

   }
</script>
```

and in html

```
   <a href="page.html" onclick="return playsound();">element</a>
```